# Deprecated GridSslContextFactory in apache ignite

Tags: java, ignite, apacheignite

I use apache ignite 2.15.0 and I use GridClientConfiguration. It has a method setSslContextFactory(GridSslContextFactory sslCtxFactory), but GridSslContextFactory is marked as deprecated. There is no other method with a similar function in this class. It turns out that this class is also essentially deprecated? How should I set ssl context factory (for example SslContextFactory instance) now?